# NeoPixel Ring Usage Without Arduino

Tags: led, adafruit, neopixel

I am looking at purchasing a [NeoPixel Ring](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1643) for a project, but need it to work without an Arduino. Once the NeoPixel has been programmed by the Arduino, will it function when powered without the Arduino? I am not looking at changing colors or anything, I want to set the LEDs to solid red and not change.

I have found in the Adafruit website that it says "NeoPixels don’t just light up on their own; they require a microcontroller (such as Arduino) and some programming." But is this only to get them working initially, or do they require an microcontroller permanently?

Answer (score 1):

No, the settings for the colors are stored in RAM on the individual devices so they need to be reprogrammed every time they are powered on.

On the other hand, it is possible to use a much smaller device such as a surface-mount ATtiny85 to program them, and [light_ws2812](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812) runs on said device just fine. And once they have been programmed it is possible to put the MCU in deep sleep so that it consumes almost no power.

Comment: "And once they have been programmed it is possible to put the MCU in deep sleep so that it consumes almost no power." -- Why bother when the MCU running flat out consumes about 0.0001% the power of the average ws2812 chain?

Answer (score 1):

I recently completed a project using one of these LED rings. I knew these were normally used with an arduino for control, but at the time I was still testing things, so I decided to buy one and mess with it.

I soldered a standard 3-pin ARGB cable to the 5v, GRN, and Data In to the ring and connected it to one of the argb headers on my PC. The results were as follows:

1. The ring did light up and stayed illuminated with the PC.
2. The ARGB header was connected to a splitter which came from a ASUS motherboard header.
3. Armoury Crate (ASUS’s argb software) was already set up on my computer and this software was what was sending signal to the ring via a splitter.
4. There were SOME LEDs on the ring that behaved as expected based on the colors and pattern set up in Armoury Crate. However, some LEDs although we’re illuminated, we’re flashing various colors that didn’t match to how it was set up in Armoury Crate.

Take aways:
These NeoPixel rings DO work without an arduino in terms in terms of receiving voltage and lighting up. However, because of how these are programmed they may not behave as expected or intended if connected to a non-arduino controller.

For my application, the multi-color pattern ended up looking nice, so I decided to keep it as is.